# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'dtd/www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/DTD/xhtml-inlstruct-1.mod'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

when i update the gradle version to 4.0.1 and then update the compile sdk to 26 because   it's the minimum sdk with this gradle version it's show me this error when i need run my app

```
Error:Execution failed for task:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug.
More than one file was found with OS independent path dtd/www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/DTD/xhtml-inlstruct-1.mod
```

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow`, Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and then [edit] your question.**

Comment: Please specify a little more

Comment: what's missing ?